# What is a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I often see a comment that a questions should be a community wiki. What is this and how is it differentiated from a normal question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/

Comment: I'm closing this since it is precisely handled by the MSO question Marek linked to.