# Effects of check-marking the Community Wiki box

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I've done some additions to a PSE question [Is the Universe Past-Eternal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105895/) whose own author doesn't seem to be very active on the site recently, and hasn't accepted any answer (-I believe mine remains the only answer submitted).  Upon my last edit, I noticed a box marked "Community Wiki", so I'm asking what the benefit of check-marking it might be, and whether check-marking it might be appropriate, and might preserve the Q&A involved.  (A lot of my awareness of physics has come from the site, and my answer now includes a reference to the posting of at least one other question on it, but I don't recollect having submitted any question directly related to my answer, partly because of an inconvenient question ban which has finally expired.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/550/2451

Comment: Further, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/280545